# Extracting plain text from html files in R

Tags: html, r, xml, text

I'm downloading a document containing text and html tags from the Security and Exchange Commission website. I'm trying to extract the main text by removing the html tags.

In my first attempt, I'm using functions from the XML package and displaying the result of the conversion in output.htmltotext. This approach fails to extract the main text of the document.

```
library(XML) 
dir = getwd(); 

download.file("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000180/0000891618-06-000116.txt", file.path(dir,"filing.html"))

# attempt 1
doc.html = htmlTreeParse(file.path(dir,"filing.html"), useInternal = TRUE)
doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(doc.html, '//p', xmlValue))
output.htmltotext = as.data.frame(doc.text)
```

In my second attempt, I'm letting the Mac system do the conversion from html to txt using textutil.

```
# attempt 2
system(paste0('textutil -convert txt ',file.path(dir,"filing.html")))
output.macsystem <- read.table(file=file.path(dir, "filing.txt"),sep="\t", quote= "",comment.char="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I find this approach quite accurate, although very time-consuming. It may take 1 or 2 minutes to convert a single document as the size of the file can reach 80-90 MBs and I have thousands of documents. I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution to this problem (maybe calling Python from R and use the Beautiful Soup library?).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) is a more efficient option than the XML package. There are also at least a few packages built to pull data from EDGAR: [edgar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgar/index.html), [edgarWebR](https://mwaldstein.github.io/edgarWebR/), [finreportr](https://github.com/sewardlee337/finreportr)

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Perhaps most of the time is spent on downloading.